# DDD - Share data and behavior between entities

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, software-design

My team is developing a system called promotions, and we are now doing the tactical modelling of the domain.

We have 4 different types of promotions and they have distinct business rules, behavior and some different data, **BUT**, they also shared many properties like: Name, Description, Initial date, Final date, and little behaviors.

Because of the differences of behavior and business rules, we concluded that they are different aggregates and entities too. Is that right? And if it's right, what's the best way to model the domain to reuse code (some methods) and the shared properties.

Answer (score 1):

This is hard to say. You can do that but why not have a shared based entity that  shares Name, Description, Initial date, Final date. this allows you to do things based on the base class if you don't care about the inherited classes models.

Answer (score 0):

You should go from a base Class containing all the shared methods and properties. Inherit from it and add what you want . If you think it will create alot of complex inheritance , opt for a Builder Pattern where you build each promotion with whats needed from it.